# Most Efficient Way of Iterating Over Large (20,000+ items) List Python

Tags: python, list, optimization, iteration, tweepy

I have a set of Twitter data that I've accessed using the Tweepy Python library. However, I'm quickly realizing I haven't collected all the necessary data. What I'm doing now is extracting Tweet IDs from this uncleaned dataset, storing them in a list, and then iterating over this list to send each Tweet ID as a query to Twitter's API. I'd like to append each returned Twitter status as a JSON object/Python dict to a list. I'd like to then write these out to a flat file or MongoDB (assuming I can learn the latter in a timely fashion). I've been trying with something like the following code:

```
long_list = [id1, id2, id3, id4 .... id20000]
status_list = []

for i in long_list:
    try:
        tweet = api.get_status(i)
        status_list.append(tweet._payload)
    except:
        pass
```

However, the above code seems to be timing out and my Python interpreter becomes unresponsive almost immediately after this is executed. I'm thinking there has to be a more efficient way to do this, but I have no idea what that might be. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Iterating through a list in python is pretty efficient. I suspect that your problem is in `api.get_status(i)` rather than in the list iteration.

Comment: Have you tried putting debug messages in there to see how things are moving along?  Something like `for idx, i in enumerate(long_list): print("Querying {:d} of {:d}".format(idx + 1, len(long_list))")...`

Comment: @JLLagrange I've tried putting in a simple `print` statement after the `status_list.append(tweet._payload)` line, but nothing prints to the console.

Comment: Can you manually get one status and see how long that takes?

Comment: I wonder if you are hitting a limit on api calls to Twitter?

Comment: Isn't it possible to query for tweet status in a bulk call?

Comment: @JLLagrange Retrieving a tweet with something like `api.get_status(id)` happens pretty much instantaneously. I had thought about the limit on API calls, so I'm a bit worried about that. Finally got a version running with a `print` statement before the `except` line, and the program comes to a dead-stop. If there's a way to make batch/bulk calls to the Twitter API, I'm not aware of it. Looking into it now. Also, I can't seem to exit the program with a CTRL + C keyboard interrupt.

Comment: For the curious, it looks like you cannot make bulk calls to the API: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/23734.

Comment: Iterating over a 20k-element list is pretty quick in Python. It's what you do in each iteration that could be slow. Hitting the Twitter API in each iteration is certainly not going to be lightning-fast, and if the server or connection hangs for any reason, your program will also similarly grind to a halt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's your list code that get it slow, not the API you called? to check performance, you can try [profile it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html), and there are graphical tools like [runsnakerun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/)

One simple way to check if your code is in middle of something is to print something,
like:

```
print 'getting status from tweet'
tweet = api.get_status(i)
print 'appending to my list'
status_list.append(tweet._payload)
```

Or you can use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module that handles nice things for you.

```
import logging
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logging.info('getting status from tweet')
```